# reset column value from 1 to count

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update column value that is auto increment. For example :

```
id  |  value  |  
---------------
1   | abc     |  
2   | def     |  
16  | sdfs    |
361 | dsffs   |
```

I need to transfer it to

```
id  |  value  |  
---------------
1   | abc     |  
2   | def     |  
3   | sdfs    |
4   | dsffs   |
```

For count of all values of that table. Also need to mansion that there are 3 foreign keys on this table for column `id`, and when I'm trying to use this query to update column value it fails with duplicate error even though there's no record with this value on any of those tables

```
set @row_number = 0;
UPDATE
  cms_page AS page,
  (
  SELECT
    (@row_number := @row_number + 1) AS id,
    page_id
  FROM
    cms_page
  ORDER BY page_id    
) AS new_id
SET 
  page.page_id = new_id.id
```

Comment: Do not change the id of a table that has foreign key relationships.  It is just that simple.

Comment: *I need to transfer it to* This contradicts with your SQL code (assuming the `value` in example data and `page_id` in the query is the same) - the values in desired result are NOT sorted by `value`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unfortunatly i kinda have to

Comment: @Akina how exactly sorting results by value will help?

Comment: The example must match the explanation - if not it is impossible to understand what do you need in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend that you do not do this.  However, one simple method uses two updates.  Presumably the ids are numbers and never negative.  So:

```
update cms_page
    set page_id = - page_id;

set @row_number = 0;

update cms_page
    set page_id = (@row_number := @row_number + 1)
    order by page_id desc;  -- remember, it is now negative
```

If you have cascading `update` constraints -- which are necessary for this to really work for referring tables -- then everything will be updated twice.  Be sure you have enough log space!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` statement, update will change the underlying data & you will be in trouble if matching data available in other table :

```
select page.*, 
      (select count(*) 
       from cms_page as page1 
       where page1.id <= page.id
      ) as new_id
from cms_page as page;
```

This assumes `id`s are in sequential manner as you stated.